# What does 'pending' test mean in Mocha, and how can I make it pass/fail?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am running my tests and noticed:

```
18 passing (150ms)
1 pending
```

I haven't seen this before. Previously test either passed, or failed. Timeouts caused failures. I can see which test is failing because it's also blue. But it has a timeout on it. Here's a simplified version:

```
test(`Errors when bad thing happens`), function(){
  try {
    var actual = doThing(option)        
  } catch (err) {
    assert(err.message.includes('invalid'))
  }
  throw new Error(`Expected an error and didn't get one!`)
}
```

- What does 'pending' mean? **How could a test be 'pending' when Mocha has exited and node is no longer running?**
- Why is this test not timing out?
- How can I make the test pass or fail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test [had a callback](https://mochajs.org/#pending-tests) (ie, an actual function, not done) but refactoring the code solved the issue. The issue was how code that expects error should run:

```
test('Errors when bad thing happens', function() {
  var gotExpectedError = false;
  try {
    var actual = doThing(option)       
  } catch (err) {
    if ( err.message.includes('Invalid') ) {
      gotExpectedError = true
    }
  }
  if ( ! gotExpectedError ) {   
    throw new Error(`Expected an error and didn't get one!`)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 54):

A test can end up being shown by Mocha as "pending" when you inadvertently closed the test's `it` method early, like:

```
// Incorrect -- arguments of the it method are closed early
it('tests some functionality'), () => {
  // Test code goes here...
};
```

The `it` method's arguments should include the test function definition, like:

```
// Correct
it('tests some functionality', () => {
  // Test code goes here...
});
```

Comment: In my case, I accidentally missed supplying a callback to `it`. The test code was indented to look like it was inside the `it`, but was actually just loose in the `describe`.

Answer (score 10):

When I was faced with this issue, the pending error was because I `skip`ped a `describe` test, and forgot to remove the `skip`, like this:

```
describe.skip('padding test', function () {
   it('good test', function () {
       expect(true).to.equal(true);
   })
});
```

when I ran it, I got the output:

```
Pending test 'good test'
```

When I removed the `skip` flag on the `describe`, it worked again.

Comment: A test or describe can also be skipped by using `xit()` or `xdescribe()`.

Answer (score 6):

A pending test in many test framework is test that the runner decided to not run. Sometime it's because the test is flagged to be skipped. Sometime because the test is a just a placeholder for a TODO.

For Mocha, the [documentation](https://mochajs.org/#pending-tests) says that a pending test is a test without any callback.

Are you sure you are looking at the good test ?

Comment: Yes - I;m looking at the right test. I can run `mocha -g 'Errors when bad thing happens'` an only that test will run, and it will result in pending.

Comment: you can also ignore suites/tests (make them pending) with 'x'.  'xit' or 'xdescribe'.